# How to make our own environments for reinforcement learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

How can we make our own environments for reinforcement learning? I have a heavy doubt that a game engine is used.. And if a game engine is used, which game engine is used that can be downloaded for free?

Answer (score 2):

Classical reinforcement learning (e.g. vanilla Q-learning) is not normally applied to games. There are some environments to play (and do research) on classical RL benchmarks (e.g. balancing pole), like [OpenAI Gym](https://github.com/openai/gym). It can be extended to your own benchmark environments.

Games, nevertheless, are a standard testbed for **deep** reinforcement learning algorithms. Probably the most popular approach is to use [Atari games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari). I believe they were popularized among the RL practitioners after the landmark article [*Playing Atari with Deep Reinforcement Learning*](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Evmnih/docs/dqn.pdf) by DeepMind. You can find multiple implementations of RL environments on top of the Atari emulator in github (e.g. [this](https://github.com/brendanator/atari-rl) and [this](https://github.com/gsurma/atari)).

Another popular deep RL game-based testing environment is Starcraft. DeepMind open-sourced their [Starcraft RL environment](https://github.com/deepmind/pysc2).